# unable to read from socket [104]: Connection reset by peer aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am doing client-server socket programming on AWS services using PHP, I have enabled inbound rules on AWS and somehow the connection is established but it's been closed prematurely not sure why. I've researched and even on AWS, I saw some article saying it's a known issue but I just want to know if there's a workaround or a solution.

was testing this because ultimately I want to route my GPS data to the same server so was testing to see if it works first, maybe I'm missing something that someone else might pick up, please please I would appreciate any help at this point.

```
----Localhost-----
C:\xampp\htdocs\weOblij>php -f client.php
message sent : '{"name":"myname","id":"fire1234","signature":"M@nt@t!0n"}'
message address : ***.***.***.***:8080

----SSH---

Using username "ec2-user".
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Last login: Tue Feb 16 19:26:09 2021 from 41.13.72.90

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
[ec2-user@ip-***-***-***-*** ~]$ cd /var/www/html
[ec2-user@ip-***-**-***-*** html]$ php -f server.php
Listening for connections
Resource id #5
PHP Warning:  socket_read(): unable to read from socket [104]: Connection reset by peer in /var/www/html/server.php on line 26
Could not read input : [104] Connection reset by peer
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-33-231 html]$
```

client.php

```
    <?php
    $host = "3.***.***.***";
    $port = 8080;
    set_time_limit(0);
    $msg = json_encode("{'name':'myname','id':'fire1234','signature':'M@nt@t!0n'}");
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0) or die("could not create socket");
    socket_connect($sock,$host,$port) or die("Could not connect to the socket");
    socket_write($sock, $msg, strlen($msg));
    socket_sendto($sock, $msg, strlen($msg), 0, $host, $port);
    print("message sent : ".$msg."\n");
    print("message address : ".$host.":".$port."\n");
    //socket_close($sock);
    ?>
```

server.php

```
    <?php
    $host = "0.0.0.0";
    $port = 8080;
    set_time_limit(0);
    
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
    $result = socket_bind($sock, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
    
    $result = socket_listen($sock,3) or die("Could not setup socket listener\n");
    echo "Listening for connections \n";
    
    class Chat
    {
        function readline(){
            return rtrim(fgets(STDIN));
        }
    }
    do{
        $accept = socket_accept($sock) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
        do{
            echo $accept."\n";
            //$msg = socket_read($accept,1024,PHP_NORMAL_READ) or die("Could not read input\n".socket_last_error());
            $msg = "";
            if(socket_read($accept,1024,PHP_NORMAL_READ) === false){
                $errorcode = socket_last_error();
                $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
                die("Could not read input : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
                echo (socket_read($accept,1024,PHP_NORMAL_READ));
            }else{
                $msg = socket_read($[enter image description here][1]accept,1024,PHP_NORMAL_READ) or die("Could not read input\n".socket_last_error());
            }
            echo $msg;
            $msg = trim($msg);
            echo "received data as:\t".$msg."\n\n";
        }while(true);
    }while(true);
    echo "socket closed \n";
    socket_close($accept,$sock);
    ?>
```

[image]